# SwiftUI: How to listen for tap event on ColorPicker?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture, color-picker

When using onTapGesture, ColorPicker's system color picker UI not pop up after user tap:

```
@State var color = Color.red

//some other code

ColorPicker("Color:", selection: $color).onTapGesture {
    print("Tapped")
    //ColorPicker's system color picker UI not pop up
}
```

The simultaneousGesture method is also not working:

```
@State var color = Color.red

//some other code

ColorPicker("Color:", selection: $color).simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
    print("Tapped")
    //ColorPicker's system color picker UI not pop up
})
```

Wrapping ColorPicker in ZStack still fail:

```
@State var color = Color.red

//some other code

ZStack{
    ColorPicker("Color:", selection: $color)
}.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
    print("Tapped")
    //ColorPicker's system color picker UI not pop up
})
```

If not add any gesture, ColorPicker's system color picker UI will pop up when user tap, but I can’t know in time when the user tapped until the user has selected a different color, it's too late:

```
@State var color = Color.red {
    didSet{
        print("This is too late.")
    }
}

//some other code

ColorPicker("Color:", selection: $color)
```

So, when user tap ColorPicker inside a view hierarchy, I need to do some operation, how can I listen for this?

Comment: Can you please send more code for investigating? It seems to be that you not call modal for this picker.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: @user14105742, did you managed to find a solution to detect that user has tapped on Color Picker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onAppear modifier and perform your action.

```
.onAppear(perform: {
     backgroundType = "color"
})
```

Comment: onAppear() does not help in detecting that user has tapped on Color Picker